# Resizing a BLOB image in PHP before sending to client

Tags: php, html, mysql, blob

I have an image of which I am fetching from a database as a BLOB however I am sending the client the full size image of which is then resized on their side. The images can get very large so I would like to resize the image before it is sent to the client.

I currently have the following code:

```
if (!empty($row['img'])) {$img = $row['img'];}
$width = imagesx(imagecreatefromstring($img));
$height = imagesy(imagecreatefromstring($img));
$resizer = $width/200;
$newHeight = floor($height/$resizer);
$news = $news . "<div class='newsItem' style='min-height:".$newHeight."px;'>";
if (isset($img)) {$news = $news . "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($img)."' width='200' height='".$newHeight."'>";}
$news = $news . "<h2>".$title."</h2><hr class='newsHr'><span>".$text."</span></div>";
```

What functions can I use to resize $img?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you. Example taken from this [Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php)

```
<?php    
// Load
    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
    
    // Resize
    imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
    
    // Output
    imagejpeg($thumb);
?>
```

To convert BLOB mage to file use.

```
file_put_contents('/path/to/new/file_name', $my_blob);
```

Comment: Hey, slightly confused here. What would $filename be a reference to?

Comment: $filename is reference to your image file on server. See updated answer for how to convert BLOB to image file.

Comment: I have this same (very old) question, which is to resize a blob. However, the answer here seems to be to resize an image file from the file system, rather than from a blob. Do these functions also work directly from a blob or do they require a file?

Answer (score 0):

Works with me!

```
<?php
function resize($blobImage, $toWidth, $toHeight) {

  $gdImage = imagecreatefromstring($blobImage);
  if ($gdImage) {
     list($width, $height) = getimagesizefromstring($blobImage);
     $gdRender = imagecreatetruecolor($toWidth, $toHeight);
     $colorBgAlpha = imagecolorallocatealpha($gdRender, 0, 0, 0, 127);
     imagecolortransparent($gdRender, $colorBgAlpha);
     imagefill($gdRender, 0, 0, $colorBgAlpha);
     imagecopyresampled($gdRender, $gdImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $toWidth, $toHeight, $width, $height);
     imagetruecolortopalette($gdRender, false, 255);
     imagesavealpha($gdRender, true);
     ob_start();
     imagepng($gdRender);
     $imageContents = ob_get_contents();
     ob_end_clean();
     imagedestroy($gdRender);
     imagedestroy($gdImage);
    return $imageContents;
  }
}

$image = '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode( resize($row['image_data'], 45, 45) ) . '" />';
```